# Using Snappy to render LavaChart on a PDF in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-snappy

I am trying to use the `snappy` library with `wkhtmltopdf` to render a chart (LavaChart) on a generated PDF but I have not been able. The PDF generates fine but the chart does not show. If the view is not converted to PDF, the Chart is rendered as expected.

Below is my code for the LavaChart and Snappy.

**The Chart Part**

```
         $chart = Lava::ColumnChart('Performance', $table, [
            'title' => 'Performance Chart',
            'png' => true,
            'animation' => [
               'startup' => true,
               'easing' => 'inAndOut'
            ],
            'titleTextStyle' => [
                'fontName' => 'Arial',
                'fontColor' => 'blue'
            ],
            'legend' => [
                'position' => 'top'
            ],
            'vAxis' => [
                'title' => 'Total Score'
            ],
            'hAxis' => [
                'title' => 'Class'
            ],
            'events' => [
                'ready' => 'getImageCallback'
            ],
            'colors' => ['#3366CC','#DC2912', '#FF9900']
        ]);
```

**The Snappy Part**

```
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('print.charts')->setPaper('portrait');
    $pdf->setOption('enable-javascript', true);
    $pdf->setOption('javascript-delay', 10000);
    $pdf->setOption('no-stop-slow-scripts', true);
    $pdf->setOption('page-size', 'A4');
    $pdf->setOption('margin-left', 0);
    $pdf->setOption('margin-right', 0);
    $pdf->setOption('margin-top', 0);
    $pdf->setOption('margin-bottom', 0);
    $pdf->setOption('lowquality', false);
    $pdf->setTimeout(1500);
    $pdf->setOption('disable-smart-shrinking', true);
```

**The View Part**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getImageCallback (event, chart) {
            console.log(chart.getImageURI());
        }
    </script>

 <div id="chart" style="margin: 10px; height: 200px; width: 50%;"></div>
 {!! Lava::render('ColumnChart', 'Performance', 'chart') !!}
```

Since the chart renders as expected when the view is not converted to pdf, I have reasons to believe the `wkhtmltopdf` does not execute the javascript has expected in the pdf version. I have the latest `wkhtmltopdf`installed but still no luck.

Library Version:

```
barryvdh/laravel-snappy: ^0.4.3
khill/lavacharts: 3.0.*
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It happens as maybe the js in lavachart is not loaded, there is one solution, convert the chart you obtained to svg then put that svg into the pdf

Comment: Can you help with a sample to code, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can show with a simple example, At first I have shown the chart on browser, The chart example is taken from Lavacharts docs(you can use yours). Keep a **Note** on
`events` with callback `getImageCallback`.

```
public function index(){
        $lava = new Lavacharts;
        $data = $lava->DataTable();

        $data->addDateColumn('Day of Month')
            ->addNumberColumn('Projected')
            ->addNumberColumn('Official');

        // Random Data For Example
        for ($a = 1; $a < 20; $a++) {
            $rowData = [
            "2020-10-$a", rand(800,1000), rand(800,1000)
            ];

            $data->addRow($rowData);
        }

        $lava->LineChart('Stocks', $data, [
            'elementId' => 'stocks-div',
            'title' => 'Stock Market Trends',
            'animation' => [
                'startup' => true,
                'easing' => 'inAndOut'
            ],
            'colors' => ['blue', '#F4C1D8'],
            'events' => [
                'ready' => 'getImageCallback'
            ]
        ]);

        return view('charts-view', ['lava' => $lava]);
    }
```

In view **charts-view**,

```
 <div id="stocks-div">
        <?= $lava->render('LineChart', 'Stocks', 'stocks-div'); ?>
    </div>
    <form action="{{ url('export-pdf') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="exportpdf" id="exportPDF">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Export as PDF</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getImageCallback (event, chart) {
            console.log(chart.getImageURI());
            document.getElementById("exportPDF").value = chart.getImageURI();
        }
    </script>
```

note the function name in script must be same as the value set for `ready` key in `events` in the controller. Upto this step you have done as well. I have passed the result obtained by as a hidden input field and posted the form to the controller.You can see in the diagram button `export as PDF`.
[image]

---

The url `export-pdf` calls the controller function `exportPdf` which willfinally generate the PDF. You need to pass the image (obtained as `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB .....`) to the controller to pass it to the view as image.

In **exportPdf**,

```
      public function exportPdf(Request $request){
        $imageData = $request->get('exportpdf');
        $pdf = SnappyPDF::loadView('export-pdf', ['imageData' => $imageData])->setPaper('a4')->setOrientation('portrait');
        $pdf->setOption('lowquality', false);
        $pdf->setTimeout(1500);
        $pdf->setOption('disable-smart-shrinking', true);
        return $pdf->download('stock-market.pdf');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }
```

The export-pdf blade view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Stock Market</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Stock Market Detail</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Oct 2020</h4>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <img src="{{ $imageData }}" alt="image" width="720" height="230">
</body>
</html>
```

The final PDF obtained looks like,
[image]