# After Search Export to PDF in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, dompdf

I have search data of the school now I like to export the searched only data into PDF. It is easy to send all just write `$school=School::all()`, but I like to send not all only searched data to PDF. For more information please see the attached pictures.

#### all Schools and it information

[image: all Schools and it information]

Once I searched I get this page:

#### searched page

[image: searched page]

Here is the code in Laravel controller.

**Search function:**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $camp_id=$request->camp_id;
    $school_level=$request->school_level;
    $school_shift=$request->school_shift;
    $school_type=$request->school_type;
    if($request->has('camp_id') && !empty($request->input('camp_id'))||$request->has('school_level') && !empty($request->input('school_level'))||$request->has('school_type') && !empty($request->input('school_type'))||$request->has('school_shift') && !empty($request->input('school_shift')))
        $schools=School::where('camp_id',$camp_id)
            ->orWhere('school_level',$school_level)
            ->orWhere('school_type',$school_type)
            ->orWhere('school_shift',$school_shift)
             ->get();

    else
        $schools=School::where('school_active','Active');
     
    return view('reports/search',compact('schools'));
}
```

Here is another function which **export to PDF:**

```
public function exportpdf()
{  
    // if i write $schools=School::all(); it export to PDF which i dont like i want only searched as it show in attached pictuer 2 
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.exportpdf',['schools'=>$schools])->setPaper('a3', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->download('School Details Reports.pdf');
}
```

Here is the **`web.php` code:**

```
Route::get('reports/exportpdf','SchoolController@exportpdf')->name('exportpdf'); 
Route::post('reports/search','SchoolController@search')->name('search');
```

My question is how to make `exportpdf()` function, and how to call from button in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use post instead of get for the route

```
 Route::post('reports/exportpdf','SchoolController@exportpdf')->name('exportpdf');
```

```
<form action="{{ route('exportpdf') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @foreach($schools as $school)
        <input type="hidden" name="school[]" value={{$school}}>
    @endforeach
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Export as PDF</button>
</form>
```

In your controller, use that model

```
public function exportpdf(Request $request)
{ 
  // dd($request->school); // will provide an array
  $schools = $request->school; 
  // then use it in your function
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.exportpdf',['schools'=>$schools])->setPaper('a3', 'landscape');
  return $pdf->download('School Details Reports.pdf');
}
```

Comment: use my another answer as reference it also has exportpdf() button, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541008/9471283

Comment: it not expor it show 404 and show the following in address bar localhost:8080. and this newPDF/%5B%7B"id"%3A1%2C"camp_id"%3A1%2C"school_code"%3A"SC01"%2C"school_name"%3A"Muslim%20Bagh%20Refuge%20Camp"%2C"school_address"%3A"Block%2020%20Camp%20Refuge"%2C"school_opendate"%3A"2000-01-01"%2C"school_type"%3A"HBGS"%2C"school_gender"%3A"Female"%2C"school_level"%3A"Hight"%2C"school_shift"%3A"Morning"%2C"school_active"%3A1%2C"school_closedate"%3Anull%2C"school_reason"%3Anull%2C"created_at"%3Anull%2C"updated_at"%3Anull%7D%2