# how to send data of table from one view to another view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just want to create a `pdf` of report of users which have different filters and on same view I have a `button` named as "`print pdf`", and whenever I click on that button the filtered data pass to `pdf` view so I can get `pdf` of required data only ,for that purpose I look around different tutorials regarding this but I didn't get my desired result as I am new in `laravel`

Comment: use view components, your question heading in quite much different from what you have written in contents what do you want

Comment: you asked how to pass data to controller from view, just answered before for another user, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167212/after-search-export-to-pdf-in-laravel)

Comment: I have three filters ,first in which i select type of report i-e user, teacher in 2nd i have autocomplete from database and 3rd is of select class .after all filtration i want pdf of filtered data

Comment: there are two ways one is to pass data in hidden values but I guess you have a lot of data , other is pass the whole object of filtered data as json as a post method using jquery ajax or axios

Answer (score 0):

you can send your data filter to new controller and  send that data to your view again.

Comment: how to send data to controller from view?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).